# LaTeX won't hyphenate a word in sectioning header

Tags: spacing, hyphenation, microtype

I have a long subsection title, and it is resulting in the warning `Overfull \hbox` because LaTeX does not hyphenate the word *"recherche"* :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[expansion=false]{microtype}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{2.6cm}{2.5cm}{2.6cm}{2.5cm}{1cm}{1.5cm}{1cm}{1.5cm}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For this test only

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Qergsdhbs fr zefdgergrtg : srmgr-zedgfser fuykug drg recherche gdtko}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]
I tried adding `\hyphenation{re-cherche}` but it does not change a thing, since `\showhyphens{recherche}` already knows this hyphenation for this word. I also tried using `re\-cherche` in the title but still without effect.
I was hoping that the [`microtype`](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package would solve it but I could not find how.

In case it helps, I am using PdfLaTeX.

Comment: the answer already given is a good one.  however, in general, results are better if section headers are defined to use a ragged right setting, for which hyphenation is only rarely needed.  blame the problem on the designer of the document class.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The answer of @Mico is the answer to my post, but thanks to his answer, I discovered `ragged right` and this is what I use, instead of hyphenation. I agree hyphenation in a title is not the best...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most document classes, by default, do not permit hyphenation in sectioning headers. Your example mentions (lack of) hyphenation in a subsection-level header; I will assume, though, that you'd like to enable hyphenation in all levels of sectioning headers, not just for subsections. To allow hyphenation in all sectioning headers, I suggest you add the instructions

```
\usepackage{sectsty,ragged2e}
\allsectionsfont{\RaggedRight}
```

to the preamble.

Adding these instructions to the code provided in the your posting generates the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know these two packages. Why do you use both? They do work in my example, but `ragged2e` seems to be messing with my whole document (but I couldn't find which package is incompatible with it). I read `sectsty` documentation and they suggest using `\usepackage{sectsty}\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}`, which works in my full document. What is `ragged2e` useful for?

Comment: And you guessed right, I was looking for a solution for all kinds of sections. I changed the title of this post using your formulation.

Comment: @fidekild - The package `ragged2e` provides the macro `\RaggedRight`, which acts very much like the basic-LaTeX `\raggedright` directive *except* that hyphenation is allowed. Given what you wrote in your posting, I got the impression that allowing hyphenation in sectioning headers was important to you. (This was prompted, in part, by the sentence "I tried adding `\hyphenation{re-cherche}`".) However, this impression now appears to have been erroneous. For sure, if you do *not* want (or need) hyphenation, be sure to issue the directive `\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}`.

Comment: Ok I see, so `\raggedright` will put _recherche_ on the next line, resolving the `overfull \hbox` warning, but without hyphenation of the word. With `\RaggedRight`, the warning is resolved using the hyphenation. Thanks again!